# Is there an IC that works like the PL2303 for TTL TO USB?

Tags: usb, serial, ttl

Is there an IC that works like the PL2303 for TTL TO USB and can connect to android device with driver?
I have search a lot but I did not find such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply use the PL2303? it's still manufactured and quite available AFAIK.
Another hugely popolar USB/TTL serial bridge it the FTDI  FT232 (*many* different versions, also bootlegged ones)

As for the Android support you could look at https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android, it should handle many chips (included the PL2303)

Comment: FT232 isn't supported by android driver.

Comment: i can't find an original ic in iran , i bought several pl2303 but it does not work.